# Fixed element using flexbox gets repositioned on iPhone mobile Safari due to disappearing menu on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, reactjs

This is a very niche issue, but I am building a React app and have a landing page where the main backdrop element is a `<div>` with `position: fixed` and `height: 100%` styling. It works very well on all desktop browsers, but when I tried it on my iPhone, the content suddenly shifts downwards upon scrolling - I'm pretty sure this is due to Safari's bottom menubar disappearing. Is there any way to 'bypass' this Safari menubar when rendering height of 100%? Here is the styling of my element. To see it in action, here is the link: https://gwtcharlotte.herokuapp.com/

## JS/HTML

```
<div className="landing-container text-center">
    <div style={this.styleOptions()}
        className='landing-image'>
    </div>
    <div className={`landing-overlay ${this.state.imageLoaded}`}>
        <div>
            <h1>GUYS WITH TIES</h1>
            <p className='m-w-container m-auto'>Bringing Charlotte together and improving our community through non-profit fundraising</p>
            <a style={{opacity: (this.state.imageLoaded ? 1 : 0)}} 
            className={'btn btn-red btn-small landing-btn'} 
            onClick={() => this.smoothScroll()}>DISCOVER OUR EVENTS</a>
            <div style={{width:'100%', height: 70}}/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.landing-container{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.landing-overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(#29709c,#4e6c7b);
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine on my iphone 6s. iOS version 11.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To size an element to 100% height in mobile Safari while not taking the menu bar into account, use the CSS `vh` unit. In your case, you will want to use `height: 100vh` on `.landing-container`.

Mobile Safari's viewport is [always calculated as if the menu bars are not showing](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832), so it seems like this is the measurement you are looking for.